# Migrate a Q&A from another Stack Exchange site (eg. Super User)

Tags: support, migration

I had a question to an Apple-specific problem and found the answer on Super User. I think the answer should be on this site and is general enough to be useful to lots of people.

What is the best way to "migrate" [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/177574/how-to-add-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-nested-menu-item) to make it available to the apple.SE community?

Answer (score 4):

The topic covered by the question you mention is on-topic on both SU and AD. It doesn't really matter on which SE site they are, as long as they can be found via the search engine of your choice.

Usually only questions which

- are off-topic on the site they are originally posted
- don't get an answer in a few days and are on-topic on several sites

are candidates for migration. To trigger migration in these cases, it's usually enough to flag them for moderator attention.